# Rejecting promise when using fetch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I am a bit confused with how to properly use fetch.  It seems to resolve even when I get an error status back.  Is the below code correct (wrapping the fetch in another promise)?

```js
function a(url, config) {
  if (!config)
    config = {};

  config = Object.assign(config, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
    }
  })
  return new Promise(
    function(resolve, reject) {
      fetch(url, config).then(
        function(res) {
          if (res.status == 200 && res.ok) {
            console.log("Promise resolved")
            resolve(res);
            return;
          }
          console.log("Promise rejected")
          reject(res);
        },
        function(rej) {
          console.log("promise rejected")
          reject(rej);
        }
      )
    }
  )
}

function b() {
  a('/test').then(
    function(res) {
      console.log('success');
      console.log(res)
    },
    function(rej) {
      console.log('Rejected');
      console.log(rej)
    }
  )
}

b();
```

(The above code should run fine in chrome via console... just copy/paste )

Comment: if `fetch` is the fetch that exists in all modern browsers, it, as you clearly know, returns a promise. So there's no need to wrap it in a promise, it only confuses things

Comment: Actually... it resolves even with error status like 400.  Hence, if I want the called to know it got an error code... I need to wrap and reject if its not ok/200.
  Though... at the moment... the above code works as expected (b runs reject)... I am looking at my code to try and rewrite the above to match it.

 Either way, the above was just an example and fetch was just what I could use to create a promise easy to demonstrate.

Comment: Looks good, with this code you get "Promise rejected", "Rejected". As expected. Not clear what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I tried to write a quick example and actually the example is working.  I am looking at my app code to try and make it match right now.

Comment: @JaromandaX  Again... how can I do this and reject on anything that is not 200?  By default fetch doesn't reject if its not 200.  When I use fetch I am expecting resolve to return something I can use.

  At the moment, I can't even recreate what I was seeing and my code seems to be working as expected in my app though.  Still looking into it

Comment: @Goblinlord - as your example code works correctly (according to you) how can I answer that question?

Comment: @Goblinlord Check my answer for how to reject promise for non-200 statuses.

Comment: I will rewrite the question a bit to match the answer... as my question didn't originally relate to this.  I would rather it be more useful if someone looks at it later =/.

Comment: don't worry, it's been asked many times before

Comment: "*Is it correct to wrap the fetch in another promise?*" - no, that's the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Comment: Many years later... looking at this question hurts my heart. I obviously didn't know what I was doing. I think this was one of the problems that helped me understand promises though. Looks so clear to me now~ Simply return fetch, and use `then` callback  and throw if not 200 if it should be an error.  Simple~ ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reject from success callback you need to do it explicitly by either returning rejected promise, e.g. `return Promise.reject('error occurred');` or by throwing.

Additionally, you should not abuse `Promise` constructor in your case since `fetch` already returns promise object:

```
function a(url, config) {
    if (!config)
        config = {};

    config = Object.assign(config, {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
    });

    return fetch(url, config).then(
        function(res) {
            if (res.status == 200 && res.ok) {
                console.log("Promise resolved")
                return res.json();
            }
            console.log("Promise rejected");
            throw 'promise rejected';
        },
        function(rej) {
            console.log("promise rejected");
            throw 'promise rejected';
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: I can't delete the question as the code is actually working as expected =/. Thanks for the suggestions for the throws instead of the what I was doing.